# How to implement `Show` interface for parameterized tuple?

Tags: interface, idris, multiplicity, idris2

I have `Coord` function that transforms an n-dimensional size to the type of coordinates bounded by given size: `Coord [2,3] = (Fin 2, Fin 3)`.

```
import Data.Fin
import Data.List

Size : Type
Size = List Nat

Coord : Size -> Type
Coord [] = ()
Coord s@(_ :: _) = foldr1 (,) $ map Fin s
```

How can I implement `Show` interface for `Coord s`?

If I understand it correctly, the problem is that with `s` erased at compile time there is no way to know what the actual type of `Coord s` is. So my best attempt is this abomination:

```
show' : {s : Size} -> Coord s -> String
show' {s=[]} = show
show' {s=[_]} = show
show' {s=[_,_]} = show
show' = ?show'_rhs

{s : Size} -> Show (Coord s) where
  show = show'

foo : {s : Size} -> Coord s -> String
foo x = show' x -- compiles and works
foo x = show x  -- error
```

```
Error: While processing right hand side of foo. Can't find an implementation for Show (Coord s).
 22 | foo : {s : Size} -> Coord s -> String
 23 | foo x = show' x
 24 | foo x = show x
              ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(,)` already has a `Show` implemention. `Coords` is just an alias not a datatype, it can't have separate interface implementations.

Comment: I tend to disagree. Check the error message I've got in `foo`: "Can't find an implementation for `Show (Coord s)`". As you can see, there is no tuple here.

Comment: Actually you might be right: `Show (Coord s) where show _ = "hi"` compiles but haven't been called in `foo` with the same error.

Comment: > it can't have separate interface implementations; it can have several named implementations though: https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#named-implementations