# How to use interfaces with parameterized tuple?

Tags: idris, idris2

I have `Coord` function that transforms an n-dimensional size to the type of coordinates bounded by given size: `Coord [2,3] = (Fin 2, Fin 3)`.

```
import Data.Fin
import Data.List

Size : Type
Size = List Nat

Coord : Size -> Type
Coord [] = ()
Coord s@(_ :: _) = foldr1 (,) $ map Fin s
```

I'd like to use `show` and other functions like `(==)` with `Coord s`:

```
foo : Coord s -> String
foo x = show x
```

```
Error: While processing right hand side of foo. Can't find an implementation for Show (Coord s).

 22 | foo : Coord s -> String
 23 | foo x = show x
              ^^^^^^
```

Earlier I tried to implement `Show (Coord s)`, but looks like it's impossible. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355399/how-to-implement-show-interface-for-parameterized-tuple) is linked question about it.

Comment: Defining `Coords` to be a `Vect` of `Fin`s would likely be a lot easier.

Comment: @michaelmesser, I don't think that's possible, because every dimension has different size, so every coordinate component has different type. As an example `(Fin 2, Fin 3)`.

Comment: Use `All` instead of `Vect` then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own list like data type:

```
data Coords : List Nat -> Type where
    Nil : Coords []
    (::) : Fin x -> Coords xs -> Coords (x :: xs)

toList : Coords xs -> List Nat
toList [] = []
toList (x::xs) = finToNat x :: toList xs

example : Coords [2, 3]
example = [1, 2]

Show (Coords xs) where
    show cs = show $ toList cs
```

You can also try using `Data.Vect.Quantifiers.All` or `Data.List.Quantifiers.All`:

```
import Data.Vect
import Data.Vect.Quantifiers

example : All Fin [1, 2, 3]
example = [0, 1, 2]

-- not sure why this is isn't included with Idris
export
All (Show . p) xs => Show (All p xs) where
    show pxs = "[" ++ show' "" pxs ++ "]"
        where
            show' : String -> All (Show . p) xs' => All p xs' -> String
            show' acc @{[]} [] = acc
            show' acc @{[_]} [px] = acc ++ show px
            show' acc @{_ :: _} (px :: pxs) = show' (acc ++ show px ++ ", ") pxs

string : String
string = show example
```